# How to pass dynamic values in "ng-if"?

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem with passing dynamic values in "**ng-if**". If I pass a static value then it's working, but when I pass dynamic values by concatenation of two variables it's not working. I tried with below code:

```
<ul class="list cart">
  <li class="cart_item"
      ng-repeat="product in orderInfo.products track by product.product_id"
      data-id="\{{product.product_id}}" id="items_list_{{product_id}}">
    <button
      ng-click="removeItem(product.product_id)"
      // If I pass a static value like "removed_31460" then its working.
      ng-if="removed_31460 == 'added'"
      // If tried to pass a dynamic value like below I am getting error as token not accepted.
      **ng-if="removed_+product.product_id == 'added'"**
      data-product-id="{{item_id}}"
      class="remove" data-id="\{{ product.product_id }}">
      Remove
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Note:** "removed_31460" is defined in my `app.js` file.

Here is the runnable code:

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.products = [
        {product_id:'123'},
        {product_id:'234'},
    ];
    let removed_id = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < $scope.products.length; i++) {
        removed_id = 'removed_'+ $scope.products[i].product_id;
        $scope[removed_id] = 'added';
    }
    $scope.removeItem = function(product_id) {
        alert('in ' + product_id);
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
<ul class="list cart">
  <li class="cart_item" ng-repeat="product in products" data-id="\{{product.product_id}}" id="items_list_{{product_id}}">
    <button
      ng-click="removeItem(product.product_id)"
      // If I pass a static value like "removed_31460" then its working.
      ng-if="removed_23445 == 'added'"
      // If tried to pass a dynamic value like below I am getting error as token not accepted.
      **ng-if="removed_+product.product_id == 'added'"**
      data-product-id="{{item_id}}"
      class="remove" data-id="\{{ product.product_id }}">
      Remove
    </button>
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work because it wouldn't work in JavaScript either. Your expression is equivalent to `$scope.removed_ + $scope.product.product_id == 'added'`.

Comment: product.product_id is getting from `li ng-repeat` not from $scope.

Comment: Oh, yes. Still, it's equivalent to `$scope.removed_ + product.product_id == 'added'`. Still not what you want I guess.

Comment: Above HTML code is in my handlers and $scope in app.js. If I declare "removed_31460" as added in $scope, I can directly use "removed_31460" in my handlers. Anyhow, I tried as you said but still no luck.

Comment: *I tried as you said*: I never advised to use anything. I'm trying to explain you what **you** did. You're concatenating two variables in your expression. And one of them (`removed_`) does not exist. If you want to access a variable by name, then use a Map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
ng-if="this['removed_' + product.product_id] == 'added'"
```

The identifier `this` can be used to refer to `$scope`.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expression Context](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#context)

---

The code can be changed to create a hash named `statusById`:

```
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.products = [
        {product_id:'123'},
        {product_id:'234'},
    ];

    $scope.statusById = {};
    $scope.products.forEach(p => $scope.statusById[p.product_id] = 'added');

    $scope.removeItem = function(index) {
        $scope.products.splice(index,1);
        $scope.statusById[$scope.products[index].productId] = 'removed';
    };
}
```

Then the template can use `$index`:

```
<li ng-repeat="product in products" id="items_list_{{product_id}}">
    <button ng-click="removeItem($index)"
            ng-if="statusById[product.product_id] == 'added'"
    >
      Remove
    </button>
</li>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-repeat Directive API Reference - Overview](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#overview)

Answer (score 1):

Try: `ng-if="removed_{{product.product_id}} == 'added'"`.

if you are dynamically adding id then the binding should be above, so if the product id is 201 then expression will be removed_201

Comment: I tired like above also, but I am getting `<!-- ngIf: removed_ == 'added' -->`. No productID after **removed_**

Comment: are you html as template or something like dust etc ? are you able to print your productID in html and see it, i.e not inside button attr, print product.product_id and see if value coming. make an fiddle and share

Comment: JsFiddle: jsfiddle.net/pguhL2es

Comment: Why should one try that? Please add some explanation to that code such that others can learn from it

Comment: @ajaj: are you trying to show and hide button in fiddle ? not able to get what you want to achieve in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
ng-if="removed_[product.product_id] == 'added'"
```

May be it'll help you out. Adding a **JSFIDDLE** will be helpful.

Try the following possibilities :

`ng-if=" 'removed_' product.product_id == 'added' "`
(**removed** in single quotes)

`ng-if=" 'removed_'[product.product_id] == 'added' "`
(**removed** in single quotes and **$scope variables** in braces)

Try this :
http://jsfiddle.net/d60rm5pw/

Comment: I remember using this code somewhere. If you could provide a JSFIDDLE ?

Comment: Put **removed** in single quotes
ng-if=" 'removed_'  product.product_id == 'added' "

Comment: hey @AjayReddy, check this out: 
**ng-if="'removed_'product.product_id == 'added'"**

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191504/discussion-between-ajay-reddy-and-rahim-nagori).

Comment: And how to do that?
I think your problem is resolved with the recent code I provided. If it is, please upvote. :)

Comment: Not yet resolved. Kindly check the jsfiddle link which I have sent